# How to protect the route by the login role in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am using laravel 5.2. I have a problem when the **user** login, they can open the **admin** page if they know the URL. This below is my navbar menu :

```
@if(Session::get('Mem_Username') == 'Guest')
<li>
<a href="{{ url ('Client') }}"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> Client List</a>
</li>
@endif
@if(Session::get('Mem_Role') == '1')
<li>
<a href="{{ url ('Lead') }}"><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw"></i> Leads</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="{{ url ('Client') }}"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> Client List</a>
</li>
@elseif(Session::get('Mem_Role') == '2')
<li>
<a href="{{ url ('Lead') }}"><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw"></i> Leads</a>
</li>
@endif
```

And I already put this in each of the controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

By the way, I am changing the `Authenticate.php` file using Session into like this below:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(Session::has('Mem_Username')){

        }
        else{
            return redirect()->guest('');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: use Gates or Policies (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#gates)

Comment: did you alter some middleware codes?  $this->middleware('auth'); should definitely work by default.

Comment: yeah I'm changing my authenticate.php code using session become `public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(Session::has('Mem_Username')){

        }
        else{
            return redirect()->guest('');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan make :middleware AdminMiddleware
```

It will create a new middleware under: `App/Http/Middleware` open the middleware, place the code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!auth->user()->isAdmin()){
        abort(404);
    }
    return next($request);
}
```

and under user model make sure you have a `isAdmin()` method that checks wether the current user is admin.

Registering a Middleware

Now that we've created a middleware, we need to let the application know the middleware exists. If you want a middleware to run on every request, go to app/Http/kernel.php and add the middleware '`isAdmin`' to Kernel class `$middleware property`.

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
];
```

If you want the middleware to trigger on some routes, we can name the middleware and use that as a reference mechanism to add it to some routes. To name the middleware, while still in the `app/Http/kernel.php`, add the keyed property to the `$routeMiddleware` array. The array key is the name of the middleware, while the value should be the `isAdmin` of the middleware.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ...
];
```

Then you can protect your routes with this middleware.

```
Route:get('someurl', 'Controller')->middleware('isAdmin');
```

Comment: Obligatory you need `web` middleware on these routes for this to work if you're not already using it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy web middleware its by default applied on all web.php routes in Laravel. Thats how Laravel knows when to process a request as an application/json (a k a ajax requests) or render html response.

Comment: Thanks. I'm well aware. I'm pointing this out for future readers.